Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cryptography Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Point addition equation in projective co ordinates

Net Score: 11 (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Net Score: 9 (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


MAC using a modified CBC mode of operation

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)


Can you fake messages from recorded message-history?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)


Combining two keys

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)


The REACT transform and Replayable CCA

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


ECDSA with SHA256 and sepc192r1 curve: Impossible, or how to calculate $e$?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)


Session-specific Symmetric Key Derivation Using SHA256

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)


Is SRP post-quantum secure?

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 4)


Secure MultiParty Computation with secret inputs for secret outputs

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 3)


I think we are doing great! After doing my site evaluation it was clear that there are a lot of high quality questions and answers on this site! Congratulations to all in our community.
I think moving from beta to a full site is a justifiable reward for such a great community!

I'm told that several beta sites are ready to graduate, but held up due to a lack of design resources. I suspect that [crypto.se] is one but I have no insider information. It could take a while. In the meantime, can we update our custom close reasons?
